# elasticsearch geohash facet in java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I found [this amazing plugin](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/08/01/server-side-clustering-of-geo-points-on-a-map-using-elasticsearch/comment-page-1/#comment-48056) for creating geohash based facets in elasticsearch.
It seems to be working perfectly alright in _head pluing. I am just not too sure about how to run this from JavaClient code.

I have code written to run a match query but am not sure how to add a geohash filter to it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "places": {
      "geohash": {
        "field": "location",
        "factor": 0.9
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought the following would help but was of no help. It throws

`Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[IokTP1RuQ520T86dxU345w][easythahr][1]: SearchParseException[[easythahr][1]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"facets_binary":"InBsYWNlcyJ7ImZhY2V0cyI6eyJnZW9IYXNoIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoibG9jYXRpb24iLCJmYWN0b3IiOjAuOX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[easythahr][1]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [facets]]]; }{[IokTP1RuQ520T86dxU345w][easythahr][2]: SearchParseException[[easythahr][2]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"facets_binary":"InBsYWNlcyJ7ImZhY2V0cyI6eyJnZW9IYXNoIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoibG9jYXRpb24iLCJmYWN0b3IiOjAuOX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[easythahr][2]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [facets]]]; }{[IokTP1RuQ520T86dxU345w][easythahr][3]: SearchParseException[[easythahr][3]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"facets_binary":"InBsYWNlcyJ7ImZhY2V0cyI6eyJnZW9IYXNoIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoibG9jYXRpb24iLCJmYWN0b3IiOjAuOX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[easythahr][3]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [facets]]]; }{[IokTP1RuQ520T86dxU345w][easythahr][4]: SearchParseException[[easythahr][4]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"facets_binary":"InBsYWNlcyJ7ImZhY2V0cyI6eyJnZW9IYXNoIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoibG9jYXRpb24iLCJmYWN0b3IiOjAuOX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[easythahr][4]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [facets]]]; }{[IokTP1RuQ520T86dxU345w][easythahr][0]: SearchParseException[[easythahr][0]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"facets_binary":"InBsYWNlcyJ7ImZhY2V0cyI6eyJnZW9IYXNoIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoibG9jYXRpb24iLCJmYWN0b3IiOjAuOX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[easythahr][0]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [facets]]]; }`

```
XContentBuilder b = jsonBuilder().startObject("places")
                .startObject("geoHash")
                .field("field", "location")
                .field("factor",0.9)
                .endObject()
                .endObject();



        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("easythahr")
                .setTypes("com.easytha.Student")
                .setQuery(matchQuery)
                .setFacets(b)
                .setFrom(0)
                .setSize(100)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

Comment: Could you put whole exception message? and did you tried this plugin[https://github.com/zenobase/geocluster-facet] which is also mentioned in article you provided?

Comment: @shyos Well, even if I were to try that plugin how do I create a query with geo_cluster facet using Java client?

Comment: I added my sample as an answer. Added two different ways to do it. I guess it works same in both plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using [this plugin](https://github.com/zenobase/geocluster-facet) which also mentioned in link that you provided. Here is a way to build its facet and it works perfectly.

```
XContentBuilder b = null;
try {
    b = jsonBuilder().startObject().
                    startObject("places")
                        .startObject("geo_cluster")
                            .field("field", Field.geoLocation)
                            .field("factor",0.9)
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

InternalGeoClusterFacet.registerStreams();


SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch("indexname")
        .setTypes("indextype")
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .setFacets(b)
        .setFrom(0)
        .setSize(100);

SearchResponse response = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

**Second way:**
After adding jar file to buildpath, you can use following.

```
b = new GeoClusterFacetBuilder(facetName, facetField, facetFactor);
```

Comment: Is there a jar file available or did you build it?

Comment: Oops, found it onhttps://github.com/zenobase/geocluster-facet/releases/download/0.0.9/geocluster-facet-0.0.9.jar

Comment: How do you use 'new GeoClusterFacetBuilder(facetName, facetField, facetFactor);' I get a compile error when I useit under setFacets

Comment: Ok figured tht out as well, it's suppose to be addFacet. Thanks